# Gravity forms Wordpress automatic email problem

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, email, gravityforms

I am trying to make a signature in an autmatic reply. Got part of the code from a colleague to work with. Once a customer filled in a form it will get an automatic email back. It looks fine in the visual maker but when a client gets the e-mail a lot of extra spaces have been added. I tried removing all the padding and such but it doesn't change a thing. Any idea how to solve this?

[![Here you can see the extra spaces between the elements][1]][1]

This is the code:

````
Bedankt voor je interesse!
We nemen zo snel mogelijk contact met je op.

Met gastvrije groet,
Het Schielandshuis
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a href="http://hospitalitymasters.nl/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
<img src="https://www.hospitalitymasters.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/HM_Logo.png" alt="Hospitality Masters" width="140" height="140" /></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0px; border: 0; padding-bottom: 20px;" width="500" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 29.45pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 15.0pt 0cm; height: 10.5pt;" rowspan="2" width="39"><a href="https://www.hospitalitymasters.nl/schielandshuis/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img src="https://www.hospitalitymasters.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/HM-Schielandshuis-schild.jpg" alt="schielandshuis" width="19" height="27" /></a></td>
<td style="height: 14px; line-height: 1;"><span style="letter-spacing: 0.5px; color: #e94a31; font-size: 14px;">HET SCHIELANDSHUIS ROTTERDAM
</span><span style="letter-spacing: 0.5px; color: #000000; font-size: 11px;">Events <a style="color: #000000 !important; text-decoration: none;" href="tel:0102762479" target="_blank" rel="noopener">010 276 24 79</a></span><span style="color: #e94a31; font-size: 11px;"><b> | </b></span><span style="letter-spacing: 0.5px; color: #000000; font-size: 11px;">Restaurant <a style="color: #000000 !important; text-decoration: none;" href="tel:0103100750" target="_blank" rel="noopener">010 310 07 50</a></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0px; border: 0; padding-bottom: 20px;" width="500" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 29.45pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 15.0pt 0cm; height: 10.5pt;" rowspan="2" width="39"><a href="https://www.hospitalitymasters.nl/on-the-spot/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img src="https://www.hospitalitymasters.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/HM-Hospitality-masters-on-the-spot-schild.jpg" alt="on the spot" width="19" height="27" /></a></td>
<td style="height: 14px; line-height: 1;"><span style="letter-spacing: 0.5px; color: #e99517; font-size: 14px;">HOSPITALITY MASTERS ON THE SPOT
</span><span style="letter-spacing: 0.5px; color: #000000; font-size: 11px;">Events <a style="color: #000000 !important; text-decoration: none;" href="tel:0702400234" target="_blank" rel="noopener">070 240 02 34</a></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K95dy.jpg
````

Comment: Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K95dy.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It may be a style conflict in your theme.

You might want to try adding "!important" to your css so that it overrides any other padding styles, ie: padding-bottom: 20px!important; or padding: 0 0 15.0pt 0!important;

Comment: Tried this but still gives enormous spaces in ex. Gmail